# Question Regarding IGMPv3 behaviour: Multicast Router appears to send Membership Report?

Tags: multicast, igmp

I'm new to how IGMP works. Recently, I was looking at a packet capture:

[image]

I see that `172.18.1.3` sends a membership query to the all hosts address, leading me to assume that `172.18.1.3` is a multicast router. I don't understand why the same host sends a membership report. Hopefully someone can help me better understand why this behaviour occurs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC3376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3376)

> > The Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) is used by IPv4 systems    (hosts and routers) to report their IP multicast group
> > memberships to    any neighboring multicast routers.  Note that an IP
> > multicast router    may itself be a member of one or more multicast
> > groups, in which case    it performs both the "multicast router part"
> > of the protocol (to    collect the membership information needed by
> > its multicast routing    protocol) and the "group member part" of the
> > protocol (to inform    itself and other, neighboring multicast routers
> > of its memberships).